# Camera Overlay not in the center

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay

I am trying to add an overlay to this UIImagePickerController instance but the result is the overlay off center.

I have created a simple red square (300x300 pt) to exemplify the problem and serve as an overlay and added that to the camera overlay, using this:

```
  CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

  UIView *containerOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];

  UIImage *overlay = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red"];
  UIImageView *overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlay];
  CGFloat midX = CGRectGetMidX(bounds);
  CGFloat midY = CGRectGetMidY(bounds);

  CGPoint center = CGPointMake(midX, midY);
  overlayView.center = center;
  [containerOverlay addSubview:overlayView];


 [_camera setCameraOverlayView:containerOverlay];
```

this is what is shown on the live preview... completely off the vertical center.

[image]

amazingly, when I take the picture and iOS shows me the picture already taken, the overlay is magically centered...

[image]

How do I center the overlay on the live camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the overlay is y-centered to the screen bounds right?

[image]

Which is what you are doing here:

```
CGFloat midX = CGRectGetMidX(bounds);
CGFloat midY = CGRectGetMidY(bounds);
```

If you want the overlay aligned to the actual image rect you need to offset the bottom black bar (it's not the same height as the top black bar).

Comment: what does this line tells you? `[_camera setCameraOverlayView:containerOverlay];` the overlay **is** being added to the `UIImagePickerController` instance and is off center.

Comment: You are right that it's being added to the cameraOverlayView. But the position is being calculated based on the screens bounds. As in: You are setting the center of your overlay as the center point of your screen.

Comment: Is there a way to get the real camera frame? I have tried using `[_camera.cameraOverlayView frame];` and also `[_camera.view frame]` and I get {0,0,320,568} for both. Any way to get the coordinates of the camera image?

Comment: Well, not that I recommend it but you could traverse the subviews and get the camera view and/or the button bar. This is the view hierarchy: https://gist.github.com/Reflejo/1f3c553363c712a8e480

Comment: Because your answer was technically right I am accepting it. Anyway, this API is stupid. Apple should not call that property `cameraViewOverlay` because it is not a camera overlay, it is a camera view controller overlay. Anyway I solved that by using AVFoundation, cause the hacking solution would not be acceptable and would probably break with time. Thanks for your help.